# Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions for chatRooms

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have chatrooms stored in Cloud Firestore that need to be secured and I'm having a difficult time doing so.  My state in React looks as such:

```
export class Messages extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.boardID = this.props.settings.id;
    this.mainChatRef = database
      .collection("boards")
      .doc(boardID)
      .collection("chats")
      .doc("MAIN")
      .collection("messages");
    this.chatRoomsRef = database
      .collection("boards")
      .doc(boardID)
      .collection("chats");
    }
```

My query in react looks like:

```
latestMessages = (messageSnapshot) => {
    const message = [];
    messageSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { text, createdAt, uid } = doc.data();
      message.push({
        key: doc.id,
        text,
        createdAt,
        uid,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      dataSource: message,
    });
}
queryRooms = async () => {
    const recentQuery = await this.chatRoomsRef
            .where("uidConcat", "in", [
              this.props.user.uid + this.state.value.objectID,
              this.state.value.objectID + this.props.user.uid,
            ])
            .get();
          for (const qSnap of recentQuery.docs) {
            const messagesRef = this.chatRoomsRef
              .doc(qSnap.id)
              .collection("messages")
              .orderBy("createdAt")
              .limitToLast(30);
            messagesRef.onSnapshot(this.latestMessages);
          }
}
```

My database structure:

```
boards(collection)
  {boardId}
    chats (collection)
      MAIN 
      {chatId_1}
      {chatId_2}
        uidArray (has only two UIDs since it's for private chat)
        uidConcat: user1_uid+user2_uid
        messages(collection)
          {message1}
            createdAt
            text
            uid_creator
            uidArray (has UID of user1 and user2)
```

I tried securing my boards as such:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /boards/{boardId} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.data(2050, 5, 1);
      match /chats/MAIN/messages/{messagesId=**} {
        allow read, create: if request.auth.uid !=null;
      }
      match /chats/{chatId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid !=null;
        match /messages/{messagesId=**} {
          allow read: if (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/{database}/documents/boards/
                      {boardId}/chats/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}).data.uidArray) 
                      && request.query.limit <= 30 && request.query.orderBy.createdAt == 'ASC';
          allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wish to have anyone that's authenticated to always have access to the boards MAIN chat and the way I have it written it works. For private rooms I keep getting an error. I've read the documents and I know that `Security rules are not filters` which is why I added a bunch of AND statements in an attempt to closely resemble my securities to my written code query in React yet I still keep getting `Uncaught Errors in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`. I am currently writing my rules to secure at the document level within the messages collection but Ideally I'd like to secure at the document level in the chat colection and check if my request.auth.uid is in the document field uidArray as so :

```
match /chats/{chatId=**} {
  allow read, write if request.auth.uid in resource.data.uidArray
}
```

I imagine securing the documents in the chat collection would be more secure but any method that secures messages is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to do a dynamic lookup in your rule based on each row of the data in this line: `get(/databases/{database}/documents/boards/{boardId}/chats/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}).data.uidArray)`

The critical point to understand here is that rules do not look at the actual data when perform queries. Get operations are a bit different because there's exactly one record to fetch, but for queries, it only examines the query to ensure it cannot fetch data that doesn't match your rule; it never actually loads data to examine. This is covered in docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) and there's a good video overviewing this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=6). A deeper dive is [here](https://youtu.be/VDulvfBpzZE?t=1344).

Role based access is a complex topic and probably not easy to answer in a Stack Overflow given how broad the solutions would be, and how specific they are to your use case. But a naïve alternative would be to list the members in `/chats/{chatId}` and use a rule like this:

```
   match /chats/{chatId} {
     // scoped to chats/{chatId} doc
     function isChatMember(uid) {
        // assumes this document contains an array of
        // uids allowed to read the messages subcollection
        return uid in resource.data.members;
     }

     match /messages/{messagesId=**} {
        allow read: if isChatMember(request.auth.uid)
     }
   }
```